# Mapping an action to area root

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an area named Area1 and I want to map an action to the root of it. For example, I have a controller (Controller1) with an action named Main that I want to map to www.examplewebsite.com/Area1.

I tried the following inside of Area1AreaRegistration.cs but it didn't work:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Area1_root",
            "Area1",
            new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Is there a way to do this with areas?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Area1_root",
    "Area1/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Main", controller="Controller1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: This works, but only when it's the only mapped route in Area1AreaRegistration.cs. Is it possible to include both this route, and the original default?

Comment: Have a similar setup in a side project and will look into this tonight if still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way with an action link. Try like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Main", "Controller1", new { area = "Area1"})
```